# Virtualbox NAT network not showing in Linux

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ping, nat, arp

I am currently Running a Bare Metal Kali with Virtualbox installed on it to the run Kioptrix Level 1.

I created a NAT network in preferences with the default recommendations.
[image]

This did resolve an earlier issue of the Kioptrix showing a failed boot of Eth0.
However I am failing to understand and resolve the below:

- I can ping from the virtual machines network to my real network, but not vice versa
- running `arp-scan -l` on the host does not show the virtualbox network ip.

Could this be a configuration issues on the host and by default should Linux pick up the NAT network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a NAT network this is exactly as it should be.

If you want to be able to treat the VMs as grade 1 systems that are directly reachable, they need to be in a bridged network